# How can I use wc for each file returned by ls

Tags: bash, xargs

I am trying to get the following information, given a folder with a lot of folders, get the name of each one with the total number of subfolders without recursivity, in order to do it fast.

To do this i am triying:

```
ls -d */ | xargs ls | wc -l
```

This of course sum all xargs ls, the problem is that I don't know how to split

```
100000
```

The second try is

```
for i in ls -d */; do echo $i; ls $i | wc -l; done
```

but returns

```
name folder
wc result
name folder
wc result
name folder
wc result
```

returned by that command instead of

```
folder_a    1000
folder_b    10
folder_c    10
...
```

is it possible to do this in one line or do I need to create a bash script?

Thanks

Comment: Using output of `ls` is a no go.

Comment: Please show use sample input & expected output in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/44425), [why not parse ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
printf '%s\n' */ |
    while IFS= read -r dir; do
        res=$(printf '%s\n' "$dir"* | wc -l)
        echo "$res $dir"
    done
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution, using `find|xargs` combo:

```shell
find * -type d -maxdepth 1 -print0 |
  xargs -0 -I@ sh -c 'echo @ $(find "@" -maxdepth 1| wc -l)'
```

Comment: this take the first subfolder.