# Bash: How to handle brackets in filepath when passing as variable in pipe?

Tags: bash, copy, rsync

recently inherited some scripts and looking to find out what is going wrong with the following script, which aims to copy a specific TSV from multiple similar directories, over to a target directory while also renaming the TSV according to the source directory name:

```
#!/bin/bash
ls /output/analysed/out/reports/sourceDir/sourceFile_\(1.23\)_reviewed.tsv | awk -F'/' '{system("rsync -avrP "$0" "$6"_identifier.tsv")}'
```

This returns an error "/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected".

I understand it is related to the "$0" in my rsync command, as changing it helps get past the error. How should I pass this variable to rsync? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Using output of `ls` is a no go.

Comment: What are some alternatives I can look into?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75660815/how-can-i-use-wc-for-each-file-returned-by-ls#comment133485465_75660815

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the error is not reported by bash, as you can see from the error message, but by sh, so I would replace the *bash* tag by the tags *shell* and *awk*. The `rsync` is executed by `awk` using sh.

The following assumes that `sourceFile_(1.23)_reviewed.tsv` is a file (and not a directory):

You are passing to `system` a string concatenated by 5 substrings: (1) `rsync -avrP` , (2) `$0` (i.e. the whole input line from the `ls), (3) a single space, (4)` $6`(i.e. the 6th field from the input), and (5)`_identifier.tsv`.

Since the output of `ls` must contain parenthesis (since actually you search for such a file with parentheses), the command to be executed will look like (for instance)

```
rsync -avrP /output/analysed/out/reports/sourceDir/sourceFile_(1.23)_reviewed.tsv sourceDir
```

This indeed shows illegal parenthesis.

Since your `ls` command produces at most one line output (when the file is present), i.e. no output when the file does not exist, you could write your program easier as

```
file="/output/analysed/out/reports/sourceDir/sourceFile_(1.23)_reviewed.tsv"
[[ -r $file ]] && rsync -avrP "$file" sourceDir
```

If you do want to use awk for whatever reason, you must ensure that the parenthesis get escaped when you pass them to `sh`.

Comment: @Jared: Just noticed that you could even drop the test for existence and only do a `rsync -avrP /output/analysed/out/reports/sourceDir/sourceFile_\(1.23\)_reviewed.tsv sourceDir`, because if the file does not exist, `rsync` will fail anyway. BTW, `-r` does not make much sense since you are just rsync-ing a single file.